# Problems with index overlap

Tags: indexing

I'm using makeidx 'as is':

```
\usepackage{makeidx} % Import the index package
\makeindex % Generate the index which is printed at the end of the document

% rest of document

\printindex
```

The problem is that I have overlap between sections:

[image: overlapped index]

Comment: This will be a fun one for creating an [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)), but you're probably going to need to do it.

Comment: Wow. I feel like a dunderhead. Of course you can't help me if I don't provide enough data. ;)

Comment: My crystal ball says you have redefined `\@idxitem` and that the redefinition uses somewhere `\textwidth`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the problem was that I had used LaTeX quotes incorrectly. Everything compiled, but the Index layout was broken. Finding it took my better half using a binary search to isolate the problem section and correcting it.